# Application SmartDevice Android to communicate with the serial port

Tags: java, android, genexus

Sirs,

I need an application SmartDevice Android to communicate with the serial port “Genexus Xev3 - Upgrade 1.”
Equipment:
FriendlyArm Tiny4412 
http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny4412

There is a project Android SDK, open source that communicate with the serial, however I cannot import it to use into Genexus.

The project:
https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/

Following the Wiki documentation, I could not import.
How to make a native Android external object?
Platforms:
•   Genexus XEv3 - Upgrade1
•   Generator: Java 1.7 web/smart
•   SmartDevices for Android.
•   Android installed 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Marcos,

You have to follow the step described here to incorporate the projects to Eclipse:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Creating+User+Controls+for+Android,

Then follow this one to create the external object:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikiExternal+Object+for+Android,

In the above link you will also find an example.

Basically in the flexible client you should add the class that implements the EO and make a reference to your external library in the flexible client.

Do you get some particular problem?

Comment: I need return parameter but in wiki not explain how to.